# Как правильно задать размер UserControl?

Tags: c#, usercontrol, wpf-canvas

Изучаю WPF и застрял с определением MeasureOverride и ArrangeOverride. Написал круглый progressbar, но по каким-то причинам при инициализации, а также если не указывать каждый раз высоту и/или ширину, то вместо овала может получится другая фигура. Если я правильно понимаю, то в идеале он должен заполнять всё доступное пространство. Прошу поправить, если не так.

Непосредственно сам UserControl выглядит так:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Round_progress_bar.UserProgBar"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         Name="UserProgressBar"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="100">
<Canvas x:Name="canv">
    <Path x:Name="path_fon" Fill="{Binding ElementName=UserProgressBar, Path=HighColor}" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
        <!--фон-->
        <Path.Data>
            <EllipseGeometry x:Name="fon_ellipse" Center="50, 50" RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50"/>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Path Fill="{Binding ElementName=UserProgressBar, Path=LowColor}" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0"> // из-за того, что при обращении к неприсвоенному значению Canvas.Left можно получить исключение, добавил нули
        <!--вертим-->
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="100,50" x:Name="din_path">
                    <LineSegment Point="50,50" x:Name="horiz_line"/>
                    <LineSegment x:Name="run_point" Point="50,0"/>
                    <!--двигается-->
                    <ArcSegment x:Name="duga" Point="100,50" Size="50,50" SweepDirection="Clockwise" IsLargeArc="False" IsStroked="True"/>
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Path x:Name="path_hole" Fill="{Binding ElementName=UserProgressBar, Path=CenterColor}" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
        <!--дыра-->
        <Path.Data>
            <EllipseGeometry x:Name="hole_ellipse" Center="50, 50" RadiusX="40" RadiusY="40"/>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Canvas>
```

Т.е. есть 2 эллипса, один сзади, один спереди, и между ними PathGeometry. В котором, одна горизонтальная, неподвижная прямая, которая соединена с подвижной прямой, один из концов которой движется вдоль эллипса. И они замыкаются ArcSegment.
Непосредственно к PathGeometry у меня нет вопросов, эта фигура рисуется как положено. А эллипсы, то швыряет в сторону, то вместо них квадраты рисует.

Я пытался задать отрисовку как можно раньше. Для этого вынес часть кода из ArrangeOverride в отдельный метод и пытался вызывать и из конструктора, и из ArrangeOverride, но это не помогло.

```
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        double min_size = 2 * ThicknessBar;

        if (constraint.Height < min_size)
        {
            constraint.Height = min_size;
        }
        if (constraint.Width < min_size)
        {
            constraint.Width = min_size;
        }

        return base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
    {
        a = arrangeBounds.Width / 2;
        b = arrangeBounds.Height / 2;

        Moulding();

        return base.ArrangeOverride(arrangeBounds);
    }

    private void Moulding()
    {
        double to_a = 2 * a;
        fon_ellipse.RadiusX = a;
        fon_ellipse.RadiusY = b;
        double thik = ThicknessBar;
        hole_ellipse.RadiusX = a - thik;
        hole_ellipse.RadiusY = b - thik;

        din_path.StartPoint = new Point(to_a, b);
        horiz_line.Point = new Point(a, b);

        duga.Point = new Point(to_a, b);
        duga.Size = new Size(a, b);

        //Canvas.SetLeft(canv.Children[0] as Path, a / 2); - подобные попытки улучшали ситуцию
        //Canvas.SetTop(canv.Children[0] as Path, b / 4);    в одних случаях, но портили в
        //Canvas.SetLeft(canv.Children[1] as Path, a / 2);   других
        //Canvas.SetTop(canv.Children[1] as Path, b / 2);
        //Canvas.SetLeft(canv.Children[2] as Path, a / 2);
        //Canvas.SetTop(canv.Children[2] as Path, b / 4);

        Position();
    }
```

Для уточнения, я задал зависимое свойство, которое следит за радиусом второго еллипса:

```
    private static void OnThicknessBarChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UserProgBar progBar = d as UserProgBar;
        double fon_x = progBar.fon_ellipse.RadiusX;
        double fon_y = progBar.fon_ellipse.RadiusY;

        progBar.hole_ellipse.RadiusX = fon_x - (double)e.NewValue;
        progBar.hole_ellipse.RadiusY = fon_y - (double)e.NewValue;
    }
```

Соответственно всё это приводит к результату, показанному на гифках:
[image: гифка с всеми элементами]

[image: гифка где одному из еллипсов задали прозрачный цвет]

Я уже исчерпал идеи, почему оно именно так работает. Пожалуйста подскажите в какую сторону идти дальше.

**UPD.** Внезапно осенило как именно решить проблему. Добавил поля чисто для диагностики, которые теперь можно стереть. И отслеживал во время работы их значения:

1)

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0">
        <Run>DinCenter {</Run>
        <Run x:Name="dinct_x"></Run>
        <Run>, </Run>
        <Run x:Name="dinct_y"></Run>
        <Run>}</Run>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run>FonCenter {</Run>
        <Run x:Name="fonct_x"/>
        <Run>, </Run>
        <Run x:Name="fonct_y"/>
        <Run>}</Run>
    </TextBlock>
```

2. 

```
dinct_x.Text = Convert.ToString(progressbar.DinCenter.X);
dinct_y.Text = Convert.ToString(progressbar.DinCenter.Y);
fonct_x.Text = Convert.ToString(progressbar.FonCenter.X);
fonct_y.Text = Convert.ToString(progressbar.FonCenter.Y);
```

3. И сами поля

   ```
    private Point dincenter;
    private Point foncenter;
    public Point DinCenter
    {
        get { return dincenter; }
        set
        {
            dincenter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DinCenter");
        }
    }

    public Point FonCenter
    {
        get { return foncenter; }
        set
        {
            foncenter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FonCenter");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
   ```

И теперь стало ясно в чём дело. Во-первых, как мне подсказали в комментариях, нужно было проверять размер Canvas. Внутри ArrangeOverride добавил

```
        canv.Width = arrangeBounds.Width;
        canv.Height = arrangeBounds.Height;
```

Теперь при запуске эллипсы выглядят как эллипсы, а не бесформенное нечто.
Во-вторых, нашёл свою ошибку. У PathGeometry я все координаты задал, а у эллипсов только часть. И видимо компилятор не понимает, что если у эллипса RadiusX = 50 и RadiusY = 50, то его центр должен быть в точке 50, 50.

```
        din_path.StartPoint = new Point(to_a, b);
        horiz_line.Point = new Point(a, b);
        fon_ellipse.Center = new Point(a, b);
        hole_ellipse.Center = new Point(a, b);
```

Конечно обидно за кучу потраченного времени, но зато узнал альтернативные способы. Потом обязательно попробую варианты и с ViewBox, и с закрытыми зависимыми свойствами. Надеюсь кому-то моя писанина будет полезна. Ещё раз спасибо всем, кто мне отвечал.
[image: конечный результат]

Comment: Странно, почему-то моё приветствие пропало.

Comment: Оберните все в ViewBox

Comment: Странности продолжаются. Сделал как вы сказали, но теперь у меня пустое окно, там где был UserControl. Надеюсь я правильно вас понял написав так:
<UserControl>
    <Viewbox>
        <Canvas>
  ...
 </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
</UserControl>

Comment: C# код свой уберите, `ViewBox` масштабирует все, что внутри под размер родителя за вас, автоматически, достаточно просто настроить элемент так, как он должен выглядеть, и потом обернуть все полученное в `ViewBox`.

Comment: Что-то не то. Закомментировал код - не помогло. Потом специально создал новый проект, где нет никакой логики в c#, но окно всё равно пустое.
<UserControl x:Class="TestViewPlusControl.UserControl1" ... d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="100">
    <Viewbox>
        <Canvas>
            <Path Fill="AliceBlue">
                <Path.Data>
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50" Center="50, 50"/>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
</UserControl>

Comment: Задайте явные размеры канвасу, например, `<Canvas Width="100" Height="100">`, это задаст явные пропорции, которым будет следовать `ViewBox`.

Comment: Кстати, фигуры можно вырезать, делается это при помощи `CombinedGeometry`. Я не спец конечно по рисованию, но всеж гляньте, мб не надо будет заливать центр. Ну и вроде изначально можно делать дугу, а не треугольник (как вы).

Comment: К сожалению у меня получилось реализовать нормальное отображение, только добавив ViewBox и внутри UserControl, и там где он вызывается, что не очень. Но зато, ваше замечание к Canvas частично мне помогло. Добавил задание размера Canvas в ArrangeOverride. Теперь, с самого старта эллипсы выглядят как эллипсы, а не полуквадратные кляксы.

Comment: Значит делаете что-то не то. Создал голый WPF проект, нажал ПКМ по нему, добавил новый пользовательский элемент управления (UserControl), скопировал туда ваш код из вопроса, удалил лишний комментарий, заменил привязки на случайные цвета, обернул все в `ViewBox`, ну а `Canvas` задал размеры 100х100, в итоге получил [это](https://pastebin.com/WFs1YDDV). Зашел в главное окно, написал там `<local:UserControl1/>` без каких либо дополнительных оберток, запустил проект, увидел [это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fYdM.png), изменил размер окна, получил [это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbSRH.png)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Для решения проблемы с размерами, предлагаю по-хитрому прибиндить размеры канваса к юзерконтролу.
- Для решения проблемы просвечивания контура другого цвета при наложении одной кривой на другую, предлагаю использовать два `ArcSegment`, которые будут просто продолжать друг друга, а не быть поверх друг друга.
- Для того чтобы не рисовать круг посередине, предлагаю использовать `Stroke`, а не заливку. Заодно и центр будет прозрачный, что удобно, если используется цветной фон.
- `Arrange`/`Measure` вообще лучше не трогать, если есть возможность не трогать.
- `ViewBox` мог бы упросить расчет координат точек, но тогда пришлось бы плясать вокруг `Stroke`, чтобы она соответствовала пиксельному размеру в зависимости от текущего масштабирования `ViewBox`. А то представляете, вы задаете 10 пикселей, а видите 20, или например 5. В текущем исполнении можно задать высоту, ширину и толщину полоски в пикселях, что вполне выглядит логично.

Пример

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="WpfAppProgressRing.ProgressRing"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppProgressRing"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="100"
             x:Name="Ring">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:MinConverter x:Key="MinConverter"/>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ProgressRing}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ProgressRing}">
                        <Canvas MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}" MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding MaxWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxHeight}">
                            <Canvas.Width>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MinConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Canvas.Width>
                            <Canvas.Height>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MinConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Canvas.Height>
                            <Path Stroke="{TemplateBinding Background}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding Stroke}">
                                <Path.Data>
                                    <PathGeometry>
                                        <PathFigure StartPoint="{Binding ProgressPoint, ElementName=Ring}">
                                            <ArcSegment Size="{Binding ArcSize, ElementName=Ring}" IsLargeArc="{Binding BackgroundLarge, ElementName=Ring}" SweepDirection="Clockwise" Point="{Binding StartPoint, ElementName=Ring}" />
                                        </PathFigure>
                                    </PathGeometry>
                                </Path.Data>
                            </Path>
                            <Path Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding Stroke}">
                                <Path.Data>
                                    <PathGeometry>
                                        <PathFigure StartPoint="{Binding StartPoint, ElementName=Ring}" >
                                            <ArcSegment Size="{Binding ArcSize, ElementName=Ring}" IsLargeArc="{Binding ForegroundLarge, ElementName=Ring}" SweepDirection="Clockwise" Point="{Binding ProgressPoint, ElementName=Ring}" />
                                        </PathFigure>
                                    </PathGeometry>
                                </Path.Data>
                            </Path>
                        </Canvas>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

Всё сделано на DP, поэтому практически не использую `x:Name`.

Как видно, использую конвертер, вот такой:

```
public class MinConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length == 2 && values[0] is double width && values[1] is double height)
            return Math.Min(width, height);
        return default(double);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

А вот и сам код, вся математика сведена к минимуму

```
public partial class ProgressRing : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Stroke), typeof(double), typeof(ProgressRing), new PropertyMetadata(10.0, OnStrokeChanged));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ProgressProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Progress), typeof(double), typeof(ProgressRing), new PropertyMetadata(0.0, OnProgressChanged));
    private static readonly DependencyProperty ArcSizeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ArcSize), typeof(Size), typeof(ProgressRing), new PropertyMetadata(new Size()));
    private static readonly DependencyProperty StartPointProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(StartPoint), typeof(Point), typeof(ProgressRing), new PropertyMetadata(new Point()));
    private static readonly DependencyProperty ProgressPointProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ProgressPoint), typeof(Point), typeof(ProgressRing), new PropertyMetadata(new Point()));
    private static readonly DependencyProperty ForegroundLargeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ForegroundLarge), typeof(bool), typeof(ProgressRing), new PropertyMetadata(false));
    private static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundLargeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(BackgroundLarge), typeof(bool), typeof(ProgressRing), new PropertyMetadata(true));

    public double Stroke
    { 
        get => (double)GetValue(StrokeProperty);
        set => SetValue(StrokeProperty, value);
    }

    public double Progress
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(ProgressProperty);
        set => SetValue(ProgressProperty, value);
    }

    private Size ArcSize
    {
        get => (Size)GetValue(ArcSizeProperty);
        set => SetValue(ArcSizeProperty, value);
    }

    private Point StartPoint
    {
        get => (Point)GetValue(StartPointProperty);
        set => SetValue(StartPointProperty, value);
    }

    private Point ProgressPoint
    {
        get => (Point)GetValue(ProgressPointProperty);
        set => SetValue(ProgressPointProperty, value);
    }

    private bool ForegroundLarge
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(ForegroundLargeProperty);
        set => SetValue(ForegroundLargeProperty, value);
    }

    private bool BackgroundLarge
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(BackgroundLargeProperty);
        set => SetValue(BackgroundLargeProperty, value);
    }

    public ProgressRing()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void RecalcProgress()
    {
        double size = ArcSize.Width;
        double offset = size + Stroke / 2.0;
        double progress = (Math.Clamp(Progress, 0.0, 99.9999) - 25.0) / 50.0 * Math.PI;
        Point progressPoint = new(Math.Cos(progress) * size + offset, Math.Sin(progress) * size + offset);
        bool switchLarge = progressPoint.X < StartPoint.X;

        ProgressPoint = progressPoint;
        if (ForegroundLarge != switchLarge)
        {
            ForegroundLarge = switchLarge;
            BackgroundLarge = !switchLarge;
        }
    }

    private void RecalcSize(double width, double height)
    {
        double halfSize = Math.Min(width, height) / 2.0;
        double halfStroke = Stroke / 2.0;
        double arcSize = Math.Max(halfSize - halfStroke, 0.0);
        ArcSize = new Size(arcSize, arcSize);
        StartPoint = new Point(halfSize, halfStroke);
        RecalcProgress();
    }

    private static void OnProgressChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProgressRing ring = (ProgressRing)d;
        ring.RecalcProgress();
    }

    private static void OnStrokeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProgressRing ring = (ProgressRing)d;
        double width = ring.ActualWidth;
        double height = ring.ActualHeight;
        if (width > 0 && height > 0)
            ring.RecalcSize(width, height);
    }

    protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
    {
        RecalcSize(sizeInfo.NewSize.Width, sizeInfo.NewSize.Height);
        base.OnRenderSizeChanged(sizeInfo);
    }
}
```

**Пример использования**

Для упрощения примера напишу через кодбихайнд

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfAppProgressRing.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfAppProgressRing"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <local:ProgressRing Stroke="100" x:Name="ProgressRing" Foreground="Magenta" Background="Cyan" d:Progress="15"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StartProgress();
    }

    private async void StartProgress()
    {
        double progress = 0.0;
        while (progress < 100.0)
        {
            progress += 0.1;
            ProgressRing.Progress = progress;
            await Task.Delay(10);
        }
    }
}
```

Вот так это выглядит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Размеры кольца подстраиваются под размеры контейнера на основе минимума из ширины и высоты (для этого и нужен конвертер, показанный выше).

На гениальность не претендую, возможно приватные DP это не очень красиво, но зато нет всяких выборок через `Children`.

Comment: Ваше решение если не гениально, то как минимум более профессионально. Конечно есть несущественный баг, если мышкой менять размер окна, но учитывая, что это было написано за пару дней - это очень круто. Я конечно попытаюсь улучшить этот пример, добавив INotifyPropertyChanged, но ваше КПД это нечто. Жалко, что с Arrange и Measure столько головной боли. Попробую в будущем реализовать разные варианты этого юзерконтрола.

Comment: @IgorPawus я в курсе про то что оно падает, если размер ячейки будет меншье критического, но это решается через задание `MinWidth` и `MinHeight` плюс немного защиты при вычислениях. Я попробовал пофиксить, но это добавило сложности в пример, и выглядело некрасиво, поэтому оставил как есть, чтобы не тратить много времени. `INotifyPropertyChanged` добавлять в сам контрол нет необходимости. Как видите, `DependencyProperty` неплохо справляются с задачей.